# Feed Me: importing google sheet values in matrix

Tags: plugin-feedme

Is there a way to import data into a matrix field using google sheets?
Ive tried using the delimiter in my fields but only one block is being created.

The docs only mention xml / json.

https://docs.craftcms.com/feed-me/v4/guides/importing-into-matrix.html